# cannot compile raspberry kernel on NTFS disk

Tags: raspberry-pi, kernel, cross-compiling

Sorry for my bad english.

I am trying to compile kernel source code of raspberry and jetson tx2 on a NTFS disk.
compile kernel source code of jetson ok, no error.
compile kernel source code of raspberry fail with bellow error message:

```
*** Error during update of the configuration.

make[3]: *** [/media/u2004/LINUX_SHARED/rasp/linux/scripts/kconfig/Makefile:39: silentoldconfig] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/media/u2004/LINUX_SHARED/rasp/linux/Makefile:541: silentoldconfig] Error 2
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'include/config/auto.conf', needed by 'include/config/kernel.release'. Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/media/u2004/LINUX_SHARED/rasp/build_output'
make: *** [Makefile:150: sub-make] Error 2
```

no error when compile raspberry kernel source code in Ext4 disk.

edit: add compile environment and script
cross compile in Ubuntu 20.04 64bit. compile aarch32 with bellow script (compile ok in Ext4 partition).

```
ROOT_DIR=/home/u2004/Desktop/dm
KERNEL_BUILD_DIR=${ROOT_DIR}/linux/
CROSS_COMPILE=${ROOT_DIR}/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-
BUILD_OUTPUT=${ROOT_DIR}/build_output
INSTALL_MOD_PATH_EXT4=${ROOT_DIR}/copy_to_sdcard/ext4
INSTALL_MOD_PATH_FAT32=${ROOT_DIR}/copy_to_sdcard/fat32
ARCH=arm
DEF_CONFIG=bcm2709_defconfig
TARGET=kernel7

git clone --depth=1 -b rpi-4.9.y https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux
git clone https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools

export CROSS_COMPILE=${CROSS_COMPILE}
cd ${KERNEL_BUILD_DIR}
make mrproper
make ARCH=${ARCH} O=${BUILD_OUTPUT} ${DEF_CONFIG}
make ARCH=${ARCH} O=${BUILD_OUTPUT} -j4 zImage modules dtbs
make ARCH=${ARCH} INSTALL_MOD_PATH=${INSTALL_MOD_PATH_EXT4} modules_install
```

please help.
thank you

Comment: Hi, what is the exact version of Windows hosting the NTFS-formatted hard drive ?

Comment: thank, the hdd formated in windows 10

Comment: could you augment your question with  a link to the kernel you are trying to build? the commands you are using for building ? if  you are compiling for aarch32 or aarch64 ? basically, could you augment it with  the information that  is needed for reproducing the issue ? this would help helping you.

Comment: thank you, i added more information in question.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, I would advise not to clone/build the linux kernel directly on an NTFS partition, since, from my own past experiences, this is probably a recipe for trouble.

The safest approach, if you want to clone/build it on a Windows 10 computer, would therefore be, IMHO, to either:

- install/use WSL2 on your Windows system (free,fastest),
- install VirtualBox (free) on your Windows 10 system and use a virtual drive formatted in EXT4 (You could import a ready-to-use (free) Linux development virtual Machine retrieved from [Turnkey Linux](https://www.turnkeylinux.org/) in a breeze).

The following procedure worked flawlessly using WSL2:

start bash.ex, and, in the WSL2 bash session, enter the following commands:

```
user@kleronomas:/tmp$ mkdir so
user@kleronomas:/tmp$ cd so
user@kleronomas:/tmp/so$ ROOT_DIR=$(pwd)
user@kleronomas:/tmp/so$ KERNEL_BUILD_DIR=${ROOT_DIR}/linux/
user@kleronomas:/tmp/so$ CROSS_COMPILE=${ROOT_DIR}/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-
user@kleronomas:/tmp/so$ BUILD_OUTPUT=${ROOT_DIR}/build_output
user@kleronomas:/tmp/so$ INSTALL_MOD_PATH_EXT4=${ROOT_DIR}/copy_to_sdcard/ext4
user@kleronomas:/tmp/so$ INSTALL_MOD_PATH_FAT32=${ROOT_DIR}/copy_to_sdcard/fat32
user@kleronomas:/tmp/so$ ARCH=arm
user@kleronomas:/tmp/so$ DEF_CONFIG=bcm2709_defconfig
user@kleronomas:/tmp/so$ TARGET=kernel7

user@kleronomas:/tmp/so$ export CROSS_COMPILE=${CROSS_COMPILE}
user@kleronomas:/tmp/so$ cd ${KERNEL_BUILD_DIR}

user@kleronomas:/tmp/so$ git clone --depth=1 -b rpi-4.9.y https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux
user@kleronomas:/tmp/so$ git clone https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools

user@kleronomas:/tmp/so$ make O=${BUILD_OUTPUT} mrproper
user@kleronomas:/tmp/so$ make ARCH=${ARCH} O=${BUILD_OUTPUT} ${DEF_CONFIG}
user@kleronomas:/tmp/so$ make ARCH=${ARCH} O=${BUILD_OUTPUT} -j4 zImage modules dtbs
user@kleronomas:/tmp/so$ make ARCH=${ARCH} O=${BUILD_OUTPUT} INSTALL_MOD_PATH=${INSTALL_MOD_PATH_EXT4} modules_install

user@kleronomas:/tmp/so$ ls -l ${BUILD_OUTPUT}
total 45445
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user      586 Mar  2 10:43 Makefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   730037 Mar  2 11:05 Module.symvers
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  2244428 Mar  2 11:04 System.map
drwxr-xr-x 1 user user      512 Mar  2 10:43 arch
drwxr-xr-x 1 user user      512 Mar  2 10:46 block
drwxr-xr-x 1 user user      512 Mar  2 10:44 certs
drwxr-xr-x 1 user user      512 Mar  2 11:07 crypto
drwxr-xr-x 1 user user      512 Mar  2 11:04 drivers
drwxr-xr-x 1 user user      512 Mar  2 11:07 firmware
drwxr-xr-x 1 user user      512 Mar  2 11:07 fs
drwxr-xr-x 1 user user      512 Mar  2 10:43 include
drwxr-xr-x 1 user user      512 Mar  2 11:04 init
drwxr-xr-x 1 user user      512 Mar  2 10:45 ipc
drwxr-xr-x 1 user user      512 Mar  2 11:07 kernel
drwxr-xr-x 1 user user      512 Mar  2 11:07 lib
drwxr-xr-x 1 user user      512 Mar  2 11:07 mm
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     4840 Mar  2 10:44 modules.builtin
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    61793 Mar  2 11:04 modules.order
drwxr-xr-x 1 user user      512 Mar  2 11:04 net
drwxr-xr-x 1 user user      512 Mar  2 10:44 scripts
drwxr-xr-x 1 user user      512 Mar  2 10:45 security
drwxr-xr-x 1 user user      512 Mar  2 11:07 sound
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user       13 Mar  2 10:43 source -> /tmp/so/linux
drwxr-xr-x 1 user user      512 Mar  2 10:44 usr
drwxr-xr-x 1 user user      512 Mar  2 10:50 virt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user 14295892 Mar  2 11:04 vmlinux
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 17819862 Mar  2 11:04 vmlinux.o


user@kleronomas:/tmp/so$ ls -ail ${INSTALL_MOD_PATH_EXT4}/lib/modules
 total 0
  844424931148038 drwxr-xr-x 1 user user 512 Mar  2 11:19 .
  844424931148037 drwxr-xr-x 1 user user 512 Mar  2 12:12 ..
17732923533530216 drwxr-xr-x 1 user user 512 Mar  2 12:12 4.9.80-v7+
  844424931148041 lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user  13 Mar  2 11:14 build -> /tmp/so/linux
 1125899907858695 drwxr-xr-x 1 user user 512 Mar  2 11:17 kernel
 1125899907858696 lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user  13 Mar  2 11:17 source -> /tmp/so/linux
```

You would then have to copy the build artifacts into your NTFS partition, which will be accessible from WSL2 in `/mnt/c` for `C:`, `/mnt/d` for `D:`, ...

Comment: Hi @nguyennamdsn if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is of course no obligation to do this.